# Building a cross-compile (mingw) environment

Tags: debian, mingw

I work in a Debian environment and it works great.  If I want to build a project, I `sudo apt install` the build dependencies, and build.

However, I'd like to cross-compile from a Debian environment using mingw-w64.  I don't have any `-w64` versions of my build-dependencies, so I'll have to build those.

Is there a method to `apt source <package>`, then `dpkg-buildpackage` using a specific toolchain?

I'm guessing [`--target-arch`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg-buildpackage.1.html) is close to what I need, but I suspect w64 isn't a supported architecture.

I see http://clang.debian.net describes a method to build the debian archive with clang involving:

```
cd /usr/bin
rm /usr/bin/{g++,gcc,cpp}
ln -s /usr/bin/clang++ /usr/bin/g++
ln -s /usr/bin/clang /usr/bin/{gcc,cpp}
```

Is that a reasonable method to accomplish this?  (but `mingw` instead of `clang`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately [there is no `dpkg`-supported architecture for MinGW-w64 targets](https://bugs.debian.org/606825), so you can’t use `dpkg-buildpackage` in a straightforward cross-building setup as you would for other `dpkg`-supported architectures. You can’t simplify things either by providing the MinGW-w64 cross-compilers as `gcc` and `g++`; cross-compilation setups need to be aware of the toolchain prefixes.

In practice you’ll need to build each dependency manually, possibly starting from the corresponding Debian package if that makes life easier. You’ll have to set up the build configuration as usual for a cross-compiled build, *e.g.*

```
./configure --host x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

There are a few packages with MinGW-w64 builds in Debian, which may serve as examples; see [`libassuan`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/libassuan/-/blob/debian/unstable/debian/rules) and [`libz`](https://salsa.debian.org/mingw-w64-team/libz-mingw-w64/-/blob/master/debian/rules) among others.

(I’m the MinGW-w64 toolchain maintainer in Debian.)